# Show that a solution of the complex ODE, with analytic coefficients, is itself analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the complex second order linear ODE $W''(z) + p(z) W'(z) + q(z) W(z) = 0$ show that the solution $W$ is analytic under assumption that $p$ and $q$ are so too.

I thought that if a solution exists, then W" exists and is continuous, so W is complex differentiable and so analytic, but I believe the problem refers to something more, if you saw the problem before or find mistakes in the reasoning, thanks in advance.